# JPQL having with exists

Tags: sql, jpql

I want to find all buckets where at least one transaction is REJECTED but not all. Ideally i would like as result a Map with key=bucket_id and value=ids in a single query.

```
id | bucket_id | status
1  | 1         | 'AVAILABLE'
2  | 1         | 'AVAILABLE'
3  | 1         | 'REJECTED'
4  | 2         | 'REJECTED'
5  | 2         | 'REJECTED'
6  | 2         | 'REJECTED'
```

My current not working query :

```
SELECT distinct t.bucket_id, t.id 
FROM Transaction t 
GROUP BY t.bucket_id, t.id 
HAVING 
EXISTS (select t.id FROM t WHERE t.status=REJECTED)
AND
EXISTS (select t.id FROM t WHERE t.status<>REJECTED)
```

As result of this query i get both buckets 1 and 2.

How can i express the condition: "at least one rejected but not all " in the HAVING clause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First have to remove t.id, otherwise `distinct` wouldnt work
- Second use T2 in the inner select so you can compare bucket_id.
- And you dont need `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` use `WHERE` instead
- Now if you need id you have to join this query with another one. Do you want first id, last id?

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d88f/4)

```
SELECT distinct t.bucket_id
FROM transac t 
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT T2.id 
            FROM transac T2 
            WHERE 
                T2.status='REJECTED'
            AND T2.bucket_id = t.bucket_id)
AND EXISTS (SELECT T2.id 
            FROM transac T2 
            WHERE 
                T2.status<>'REJECTED'
            AND T2.bucket_id = t.bucket_id)
```

**EDIT**

If status only have 2 posible values this is another solution much simpler. Meaning `Exists` another transac with diferent status to the one you are looking.

```
SELECT distinct t.bucket_id
FROM transac t 
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT T2.id 
            FROM transac T2 
            WHERE 
                T2.status <> t.status
            AND T2.bucket_id = t.bucket_id)
```

Comment: There can be more than 2 statuses, thank you for your answer man!